# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, arrays, csv, compiler-errors, java-8

This is my first big project in Java. I have been stuck with this error for so many hours. I assume I'm making a mistake because of string. I apologise if my code make no sense. I'm trying to learn my mistakes. Can you please help me figure out my mistake ?

```
    InfoGain = new double[noOfAttributes];  
    GainRatio = new double [noOfAttributes];
    findUnique();
```

Comment: You're trying to create an array that has a negative size. The exception is even named after it.

Answer (score 0):

You create two arrays of doubles of length `noOfAttributes - 1`. However, at the moment you create them, the `noOfAttributes` is still 0, so you receive size `-1` which is illegal.

Look, you set `noOfAttributes` in the conditional expression. If you don't enter the `if-statement` it'll be 0 then.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to rectify it ?

Comment: I gave you the reason of the Exception. It occurs due to the business logic issues. You have to fix it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

an Array of size 0 is possible,but not of negative size

```
int []x=new int[0];     //this is possible.
int []x=new int[-4];   // this is not possible
```

so check **noofAttributes** value,it may be negative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand, first that the arrays in Java start with `0` as their first index.

When you write

`InfoGain = new double[noOfAttributes-1];`

No of attributes can be initially 0, so `InfoGain` will try to index `-1` in the array, which won't exist and hence it gives you this exception.

Try using this: `InfoGain = new double[noOfAttributes];` for both the array and essentially it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the above error with simple if-else condition as below:

```
if(noOfAttributes > 0){
     InfoGain = new double[noOfAttributes];  
     GainRatio = new double [noOfAttributes];
}
else{
     InfoGain = new double[INITIAL_VALUE];  
     GainRatio = new double [INITIAL_VALUE];
}
findUnique();
```